# Showing that $A_q(n,1)=q^n$ in the Main Coding Theory Problem.

Tags: proof-explanation, coding-theory

Let $A$ be an alphabet of size $|A|:=q\in\Bbb Z^+$ and let $n,d\in \Bbb Z^+$ be positive integers. We denote by $A_q(n,d)$ the largest value of $M$ such that a $q$-ary $(n,M,d)$-code $C\subseteq A^n$ exists. That is, 
$$A_q(n,d):=\max\{M\in \Bbb N: \exists\ (n,M,d)\text{-code } C\subseteq A^n \text{ over } A \} \in \Bbb N.$$

I am struggling to understand something which seems to be very easy. Take $q\geq 2$. We want to show that 
$$A_q(n,1)=q^n.$$
 We are searching for the maximum $M$ such that a $q$-ary $(n,M,1)$-code $C$ exists.

We take our code to be $C:=A^n$, that is the set of all words of length $n\in \Bbb Z^+$. So $M=|C|=q^n$.

Now we have to show that $\mathrm{d}(C)=1$. Hill's book says that since the codewords of $C$ are 
 distinct, it is $\mathrm{d}(C)\geq 1$.

My question **how do we conclude** that $\mathrm{d}(C)=1$ and not $\mathrm{d}(C)>1$?

Sorry if the question is trivial, I am a little bit confused.

Comment: Every element of $A^n$ is a codeword. Surely there exists pairs of vectors that differ at only a single position.

Comment: @Jyrki Thank you for your comment. Since $|A|=q\geq 2$, I can understand that there exist 2 code words which differ at only one position. For example, if $A=\{a_1,a_2\}$, then $x:=(a_1,a_1,\dots,a_1),y:=(a_2,a_1,\dots,a_n) \in A^n$ and $d(x,y)=1$. So $d(A^n)=1$. But does he mention that it is at least one and not exactly one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d(C) = 1$ is actually trivial.

This means the minimal distance between codewords is $1$.

Your code is $C:= A^n$.

Since $|A|\geq 2$, there are at least different two codewords $c,c'$, and then $d(c,c') \geq 1$.

However, the minimum is trivially attained. Let $c\in C=A^n$ be any codeword. Change $c$ in one position and write the newly obtained word as $a \in A^n = C$. Then clearly $d(a,c) = 1$ and thus $d(a,c) \leq 1$.

Combining both inequalities, we get $d(C) = 1$.